# PhoneGap-2.9.0 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError); not working

Tags: android, cordova

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() { alert('onDeviceReady Function works');
        var option = {frequency:500,maximumAge: 0, timeout: 1000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, option );
    }

    function onSuccess(position) { alert("It Works!!!");
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude  + '<br />' +
                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function onError(error) {
         //alert(error);
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

 </script>


<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
```

Above code `deviceready()` function is working fine but `alert("It Works!!!");` not working. Please tell me why it is not working in my device emulator?

I am getting error message.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Any errors in LogCat?

Comment: Yes please check updated question again

Comment: Try increasing _timeout_ and also increase _maximumAge_ 
`{ maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true };`

Answer (score 0):

Increase *timeout* to '5000' or '10000' and also increase *maximumAge*

```
 { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
```

Check the [PhoneGap Error documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#PositionError) .

Comment: I have increase timeout 10000. I am getting same error message alert after 10second

Comment: You are testing in device or emulator?

Comment: i am testing in emulator